# Exclude complete package while building war/jar in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

After a lot of head-scratching and going round in circles at websites and StackOverflow I managed to get my Spring boot RESTful web service deployed as a war file into Tomcat, using Maven. But here I want to make war file as per the specific project with exclude of a couple of packages in common code base.

Using "clean package -f PomFile2.xml" to select the pom file,

Facing problem while doing exclusion of packages making war file, after referring a couple of questions and googling tried "excludePackageNames", "excludeGroupIds", and "excludes" within the configuration, but seeing the exclusion packages within the war file.

the snippet of the pom.xml is,

```
<build>

    <finalName>FirstspringBoot</finalName>

    <sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${app.name}</warName>
                <attachClasses>false</attachClasses>
                <archiveClasses>false</archiveClasses>
                <outputDirectory>${appserver.home}/SpringBoot</outputDirectory>
                <excludePackageNames>com.demo.test.controller.journey1.*:com.demo.test.controller.journey2.*:com.demo.test.controller.journey3.*:com.demo.test.controller.journey4.*:com.demo.test.controller.journey4.*</excludePackageNames>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please help me in exclusion of the package while making war file for specific war file per project.

Comment: First remove your configuration of `<sourceDirectory>...</sourceDirectory>` and start following the conventions..furthemore if you want to have war simply set the packaging to `war`..apart from that why would you like to exclude the packages? It looks like those you would like to exclude are test packages....

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks for the reply, tried building war after removing sourceDirectory, but no luck. I'm using the same code base for two projects, so I want to exclude the certain java packages which are not required.

Comment: Check the directory structure first ...src/main/java production code, src/test/java unit test code ...etc. After it should work otherwise doing something different wrong...BTW: Try to build on plain command line without IDE...

Comment: @khmarbaise, project structure is fine only, I'll try to build from the command line.

Comment: @khmarbaise, tried from the command line as well, still seeing the excluded packages in the built war file.